# Google Maps block touch events on Windows Phone

Tags: google-maps, mobile, windows-phone, touch-event

I've got basic google maps implemented on my site. I've put some custom controls (basic DIVs with touch events) over the map area and they work great on all devices.

The problem I have with Windows phones is that google maps somehow blocks all events on top of it. My controls are not responding at all. If I swipe on controls DIV I have on top of maps it doesn't do anything but scroll the map.

I'm using basic touch events like touchstart, touchmove and touchend for my controls. I'm also using stopPropagation inside events. All controls DIVs have z-index bigger than map and as I said everything works on Android and iOS.

Comment: Can you provide us your site, or some demo code on fiddle? I tried the [official sample](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/control-custom) on my phone and I did not see this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help but I've figured this one out. The problem was in how I implemented touch events.

I've added click events for windows phone and now it works as it should.